# floating exception using icc compiler

Tags: c++, exception, boolean, algebra, floating-point-exceptions

I'm compiling my code via the following command:

```
icc -ltbb test.cxx -o test
```

Then when I run the program:

```
time ./mp6 100 > output.modified
Floating exception
4.871u 0.405s 0:05.28 99.8%     0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

I get a "Floating exception". This following is code in C++ that I had before the exception and after:

```
// before
if (j < E[i]) {
   temp += foo(0, trr[i], ex[i+j*N]);
}

// after
temp += (j < E[i])*foo(0, trr[i], ex[i+j*N]);
```

This is boolean algebra... so (j < E[i]) is either going to be a 0 or a 1 so the multiplication would result either in 0 or the foo() result. I don't see why this would cause a floating exception. 
This is what foo() does:

```
int foo(int s, int t, int e) {
    switch(s % 4) {
        case 0:
            return abs(t - e)/e;
        case 1:
            return (t == e) ? 0 : 1;
        case 2:
            return (t < e) ? 5 : (t - e)/t;
        case 3:
            return abs(t - e)/t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

foo() isn't a function I wrote so I'm not too sure as to what it does... but I don't think the problem is with the function foo(). Is there something about boolean algebra that I don't understand or something that works differently in C++ than I know of? Any ideas why this causes an exception?

Thanks,
Hristo

Comment: What do you mean by "Floating exception"? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Are `i`, `j`, `N`, etc. all integers?

Comment: @Gabe. Yes they are all integers. @Marcelo. That is all the information I have. That is the only thing that is printed to the terminal. "Floating exception".

Comment: Very strange. Is it easy to try this with gcc (or VC++ on Windows)?

Comment: @ Marcelo. I haven't thought about that... I'll give it a try. I'm using Intel's TBB for parallelization which is why I need to compile using icc. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I just tried it with g++. This was the output.

`Floating point exception

real 0m0.550s
user 0m0.150s
sys 0m0.021s
`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, on most modern OSes, `Floating exception` only occurs when **integer** division by zero occurs.  That's backwards, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost certainly dividing by zero in `foo`.

A simple program of

```
int main()
{
    int bad = 0;
    return 25/bad;
}
```

also prints

> `Floating point exception`

on my system.

So, you should check whether `e` is 0 when `s % 4` is zero, or whether `t` is 0 when `s % 4` is 2 or 3.  Then return whatever value makes sense for your situation instead of trying to divide by zero.

---

@hristo:  C++ will still evaluate the right-hand-side of a multiplication even if the left-hand-side is zero.  It doesn't matter that the result *should be* zero; it matters that `foo` was called and evaluated and caused an error.

Sample source:

```
#include <iostream>
int maybe_cause_exception(bool cause_it)
{
    int divisor = cause_it ? 0 : 10;
    return 10 / divisor;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Do not raise exception: " << maybe_cause_exception(false) << std::endl;

    int x = 0;

    std::cout << "Before 'if' statement..." << std::endl;

    if(x)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside if: " << maybe_cause_exception(true) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Past 'if' statement." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Cause exception: " << x * maybe_cause_exception(true) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> `Do not raise exception: 1`
>
> `Before 'if' statement...`
>
> `Past 'if' statement.`
>
> `Floating point exception`

Comment: Then why would it work the first time compare to the second... the arguments to foo() are exactly the same?

Comment: @Hristo: The first time, `foo` was not called with the argument causing the crash.

Comment: Because in the first variant the function is only called when `j < E[i]`, but in your "after" code it's called in all cases.

Comment: @ Mark. Well, if it didn't go inside the `if` statement in the first version of the code, then (j < E[i]) would be 0 so then the multiplication would result in 0. This isn't sequential code... the "before" is on version, and the "after" replaces what it was before.

Comment: @Hristo: The multiplication by zero *does not matter*.  `foo` is still evaluated, even when multiplied by zero.  I've posted some code to demonstrate this.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I understand that foo() is still evaluated, now I just have to figure out why it is causing a division by 0 when it has the same parameters as before. Thanks.

Comment: I understand now... before I was not doing a certain iteration because the if statement will evaluate to false.. but now I will do that iteration which would cause the exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you are dividing by 0? It could be that an integer division by 0 is surfacing as a "Floating exception".

When you have the `if`, the computation isn't done if a division by 0 would happen. When you do the "Boolean algebra", the computation is done regardless, resulting in a divide by 0 error.

You're thinking that it will be `temp += 0*foo(...);` so it doesn't need to call foo (because 0 times anything will always be 0), but that's not how the compiler works. Both sides of a `*` have to be evaluated.

Comment: It is possible, but the only thing that was changed was that I multiplied by `(j < E[i])`... foo() isn't changed nor are its parameters.

Comment: No... I wasn't thinking that foo() won't be called, I was thinking that this will evaluate to 0. I didn't think foo() would cause an exception because the parameters are the same.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not tell you the exact cause of your floating-point exception, I can provide some information you might find useful in investigating future floating-point errors.  I believe [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752499/floating-exception-using-icc-compiler/2752512#2752512) has already shed some light on why you are having this particular problem.

---

The most portable way of determining if a floating-point exception condition has occurred and its cause is to use the floating-point exception facilities provided by C99 in [fenv.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/fenv.h.html).  There are 11 functions defined in [fenv.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenv.h) for manipulating the floating-point environment (see [fenv(3) man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fenv.3.html)).  You may also find [this article](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP03-C.+Detect+and+handle+floating+point+errors) to be of interest.

---

On POSIX compliant systems, `SIGFPE` is sent to a process when in performs an erroneous arithmetic operation and this does not necessarily involve floating-point arithmetic.  If the `SIGFPE` signal is handled and `SA_SIGINFO` is specified in the `sa_flags` for the call to [`sigaction(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), the `si_code` member of the `siginfo_t` structure should specify the reason for the fault.

From the [wikipedia `SIGFPE` article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE):

> A common oversight is to consider division by zero the only source of SIGFPE conditions. On some architectures (IA-32 included<sup>[citation needed]</sup>), integer division of INT_MIN, the smallest representable negative integer value, by −1 triggers the signal because the quotient, a positive number, is not representable.

Answer (score 0):

When I suggested replacing branch with multiplication by one or zero, I did not consider that if statements may be guarding against numerical exception. multiplication trick still evaluates expression, but effectively throws it away.  for small enough expression, such trick is better than conditional, but you have to make sure expression can evaluate.

You can still use multiplication trick, if you slightly transform denominator.
instead of `x/t` use `x/(t + !t)` which does not affect anything if denominator is nonzero (you are adding zero then)but allows denominator `t = 0` to be compute, and then thrown away by multiplying by zero.

And sorry, but be careful with my suggestions, I do not know all details of your program.  plus, I tend to go wild about replacing branches with "clever" Boolean expressions

Comment: Yes I tried your suggestion with the multiplication trick, but the problem was that the `if` was preventing foo() from causing exceptions and when I used multiplication, foo() was no longer being protected and that resulted in floating exceptions. I can't edit foo(), so I am forced to keep the `if` statement. Thanks for your suggestions!